# How to increment the last number in a string; bash

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a string that looks something like
`/foo/bar/baz59_ 5stuff.thing`

I would like to increase the last number (5 in the example) by one, if it's greater than another variable.  A 9 would be increased to 10. Note that the last number could be multiple digits also; also that "stuff.thing" could be anything; other than a number; so it can't be hard coded.

The above example would result in `/foo/bar/baz59_ 6stuff.thing`

I've found multiple questions (and answers) that would extract the last number from the string, and obviously that could then be used in a comparison. 
 The issue I'm having is how to ensure that when I do the replace, I only replace the last number (since obviously I can't just replace "5" for "6").  Can anyone make any suggestions?

awk/sed/bash/grep are all viable.

Comment: If the last number is 9, what's the desired outcome? What if it's 59?

Comment: if the last number is 9; then the desired is 10.  59; 60.  99->100 etc   (question updated for posterity)

Comment: It's always preceded by an underscore this last number of yours?

Comment: @gboffi no;  the previous character is not fixed.

Comment: `if it's greater than a script argument` you mean the whole string, or the number?  if the number, do you mean increment the last number in the string that is greater than an argument, or increment the last number in the string if it is greater than an argument?

Comment: not clear what you mean by `if it's greater than a script argument` for your example is it to be incremented if the arg is given as 4?

Comment: @karakfa updated question.  So if I'm trying to compare to 3 for example; the 5 would be increased; but if comparing to 7 then the 5 would be unchanged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Thanks to @EdMorton for pointing out the further requirement of the number exceeding a threshold. That can be done like this:

```
perl -spe 's/(\d+)(?!.*\d+)/$1>$thresh? $1+1 : $1/e' <<<  "abc123_456.txt" -- -thresh=500
```

**Original Answer**

You can evaluate/calculate a replacement with `/e` in Perl regexes. Here I just add 1 to the captured string of digits but you can do more complicated stuff:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?!.*\d+)/$1+1/e' <<< "abc123_456.txt"
abc123_457.txt
```

The `(?!.*\d+)` is (hopefully) a negative look-ahead for any more digits.

The `$1` represents any sequence of digits captured in the capture group `(\d+)`.

Note that this would need modification to handle decimal numbers, negative numbers and scientific notation - but that is possible.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly; and even handles a string containing quotes

Comment: or `s/.*(?<!\d)\K(\d+)/$1+1/sea`

Comment: @EdMorton Well spotted! I hadn't seen that, but have added it in now.

Comment: or `s/(\d+)(?=\D*$)/$1+1/ea`

Comment: Thank you all for your alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Using bash regular expression matching:

```
$ f="/foo/bar/baz59_ 99stuff.thing"
$ [[ $f =~ ([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)$ ]]
```

OK, what do we have now?

```
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="99stuff.thing" [1]="99" [2]="stuff.thing")
```

So we can construct the new filename

```
if [[ $f =~ ([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)$ ]]; then
    prefix=${f%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}           # remove "99stuff.thing" from $f
    number=$(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]} + 1 ))  # use "10#" to force base10
    new=${prefix}${number}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo $new
fi
# => /foo/bar/baz59_ 100stuff.thing
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk -v t=3 'match($0,/(.*)([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)$/,a) && a[2]>t{a[2]++; $0=a[1] a[2] a[3]} 1' file
/foo/bar/baz59_ 6stuff.thing
```

Just set `t` to whatever your threshold value is for incrementing, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v t=7 'match($0,/(.*)([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)$/,a) && a[2]>t{a[2]++; $0=a[1] a[2] a[3]} 1' file
/foo/bar/baz59_ 5stuff.thing
```

Answer (score 1):

> if it's greater than a script argument.

If I get it correctly(I am assuming you are passing an argument through a script and if its value is greater than string's 2nd field digit then increase 1 into that 2nd field's digit), could you please try following once.

```
cat script.ksh
value=$1
echo "/foo/bar/baz59_ 5stuff.thing" | 
awk -v arg="$value" '
  match($2,/[0-9]+/){
    val=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    val=val<arg?val+1:val
    $2=val substr($2,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1'
```

Here is an example when I run script.ksh it gives following output.

```
/script.ksh 7
/foo/bar/baz59_ 6stuff.thing
```

Comment: @UKMonkey, could you please check this one also once and let me know if this works for you?

Comment: @UKMonkey, cool glad that it helped  you, why I have specifically asked is no other solution have taken argument from script and compared it, so I wanted to make sure I understood question correctly, if you tested by passing argument then cool :)

Comment: it was the principle behind the replacement that I cared about - the full implementation such as how to plug in the string etc is a worry I didn't want to infect the question with.

Comment: @UKMonkey, well(if I get it correctly) if that is complete requirement then you need not to worry now, you have complete solution now :)

Answer (score 1):

An awk:

```
$ echo /foo/bar/baz59_ 99stuff.thing |
awk '
/[0-9]/ {
    rstart=1                                    # keep track of the start
    while(match(substr($0,rstart),/[0-9]+/)) {  # while numbers last
        rstart+=RSTART+RLENGTH-1                # increase rstart
        rlength=RLENGTH                         # remember length too
    }
    v=substr($0,rstart-rlength,rlength)+1                    # increase last number
    print substr($0,1,rstart-rlength-1) v substr($0,rstart)  # print in parts
    next
}1'                                             # in case there was no number
/foo/bar/baz59_ 100stuff.thing
```

**Edit**:

Whoops, I missed the argument requirement (*increase the last number - - by a one, if it's greater than a script argument*):

```
$ echo /foo/bar/baz59_ 99stuff.thing |
awk -v arg=100 '
/[0-9]/ {
    rstart=1
    while(match(substr($0,rstart),/[0-9]+/)) {
        rstart+=RSTART+RLENGTH-1
        rlength=RLENGTH
    }
    v=substr($0,rstart-rlength,rlength)
    if(0+v>arg) {                           # test if v greater that argument
        print substr($0,1,rstart-rlength-1) v+1 substr($0,rstart)
        next
    }
}1'
```

Output now:

```
/foo/bar/baz59_ 99stuff.thing
```

Comment: Updated with the script argument requirement. Missed it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter `gnu awk` approach:

```
cat incr.awk
{
   n = split($0, a, /[0-9]+/, b)
   for(i=1; i<n; i++)
      s = s a[i] b[i] + (b[i] < max && i == n-1 ? 1 : 0)
   print s a[i]
}
```

Then use it as:

```
awk -v max=80 -f incr.awk <<< '/foo/bar/baz59_ 5stuff.thing'
/foo/bar/baz59_ 6stuff.thing

awk -v max=80 -f incr.awk <<< '/foo/bar/baz59_ 79stuff.thing'
/foo/bar/baz59_ 80stuff.thing


awk -v max=80 -f incr.awk <<< '/foo/bar/baz59_ 90stuff.thing'
/foo/bar/baz59_ 90stuff.thing

awk -v max=80 -f incr.awk <<< '/foo/bar/baz59_ 80stuff.thing'
/foo/bar/baz59_ 80stuff.thing

awk -v max=80 -f incr.awk <<< '/foo/bar/stuff.thing'
/foo/bar/stuff.thing
```

Answer (score 0):

if the 'testing' number is in 'bound' variable:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$bound=6} s{(\d+)_(\d+)(?!.*\d+)}{ $i=$2+1;($i>$bound? $1+1:$1)."_".$i}e' <<<"/foo/bar/baz59_5stuff.thing"
/foo/bar/baz59_6stuff.thing
```